# Как поймать событие изменения класса у body, что бы добавить обработчик

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, скрипт

Ситуация такая, есть проект на ангуляре (хз каком) и есть некая функция, которая меняет расширение у картинок в ie и edge. при первой загрузке страницы скрипт срабатывает и картинкам становится хорошо, однако перейдя на другую страницу сайта картинки снова становятся прежними и некрасивыми, а скрипт не работает.
Однако перезагрузив страницу полностью всё снова становится хорошо (скрипт работает 1 раз)
Суть такова, приклеить куда-то функцию, чтобы при переходе между страницами сайта скрипт срабатывал.
Я заметил, что во время перехода по страницам, у body меняется класс во время загрузки. Он меняется при помощи className =+ "имяКласса", и убив час на поиски я так и не смог научится ловить событие изменения класса.

Comment: Ищите событие смены маршрута в Ангуляре и вызывайте функцию для модификации картинок при возникновении такого события.

Comment: А у вас есть возможность модифицировать код на `angular`?